# Passing string with a singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, singleton, global-variables

I'm fairly new to iOS programming and was trying to pass a user input string from a text field to another view with the use if singletons. The intent of my app is to have a user type in a vehicle name or model, and then show the Craigslist search for it.

After looking at some youtube guides, it seems like my code should be working, but the string isn't being passed, it only shows up as (null). Can anyone tell what's wrong?

These are my singleton files and code related to setting and getting the string, I have import statements on all of my files for `GlobalVariables.h`:

GlobalVariables.h

```
@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject{

    NSString *globalStr;

}

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *globalStr;

+(GlobalVariables *) singleObj;

@end
```

GlobalVariables.m

```
@implementation GlobalVariables

@synthesize globalStr;


static GlobalVariables *singleObj = nil;

+ (GlobalVariables *) singleObj{
    @synchronized(self){
        if (singleObj==nil){
            singleObj = [[self alloc]init];
        }
    }
    return singleObj;
}

@end
```

Code to set the globalStr: *`nameTextField` is the user input field

```
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    textToPass = nameTextField.text;
    [self passValues];
}

- (void) passValues{
    GlobalVariables *myVar = [GlobalVariables singleObj];
    myVar.globalStr = textToPass;

}
```

Code to get the globalStr

```
GlobalVariables* myVar = [GlobalVariables singleObj];
NSString *searchStr = myVar.globalStr;
```

Comment: as Matt suggested in the answer below, are you sure that textToPass it not `nil`?

Comment: Please, please, please do not use singletons to "pass" parameters.  You will shoot yourself in the foot.  Learn how to use proper parameters and view controller fields.

Comment: How is this even compiling? You have an instance variable and also a property with the same name and type? I suggest that you remove the instance variable declaration '{ NSString *globalStr;}' and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In your -passValues method, could you change it to this and check if textToPass is not nil?
Is textToPass a property?

```
- (void) passValues{

    NSLog(@"textToPass: %@", textToPass);

    GlobalVariables *myVar = [GlobalVariables singleObj];
    myVar.globalStr = textToPass;

}
```

Your code may need to look something like this:

```
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    textToPass = nameTextField.text;
    [self passValues:textToPass];
}

- (void)passValues:(NSString *)text
{
    GlobalVariables *myVar = [GlobalVariables singleObj];
    myVar.globalStr = text;

}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry. I actually meant to suggest that he explicitly pass the string. I edited my answer.

Comment: textToPass is a NSString.

Comment: and it contains a string in it before you set it to the singleton's property?

Comment: It contains the string from the nameTextField, the user input text field.